# What is the hybridisation of the bridging oxygen atoms in the borax anion?

Tags: bond, hybridization, boron-family

Below is a neat looking borax anion.

[image: structure of the borax anion]

While exploring the molecule in a computer simulation (Gaussian 16, level of theory: HF/3-21G), I found that the oxygen atoms in the 8-membered outer ring had sp<sup>2</sup> hybrid orbitals. My curiosity led me to question the presented data. Using Natural Bond Orbital analysis, I found out that:

```
BD(1)B1(O2)
1s(20.94%)p3.78(79.06%)
BD(1)O2(B1)
2s(10.48%)p8.54(89.52%)

BD(1)O2(B3)
2s(23.60%)p3.24(76.40%)
BD1(1)B3(O2)
3s(36.38%)p1.75(63.62%)

LP(1)O2
s(17.50%)p4.71(82.50%)
LP(2)O2
s(48.39%)p1.07(51.61%)
```

Here BD denotes a 2-centered bond with atom(i)atom(j) and LP(i) denotes the lone pair and the s,p characters follow. My question is as follows:

Given the chaotic data, how does one analyse or interpret the harmony and claim that the oxygen[2] is indeed ~sp<sup>2</sup> hybridised?

What is the correct hybridisation of the oxygen atoms not connected to a hydrogen?

Comment: NBOA was done using Engine provided as Gaussian, theory: Hartree-Fock in basis set 3-21G

Comment: Oh, than that wouldn't be borax, because it's a salt of such anion and you made another mistake in simulation. not to say this title is particularly vague.

Comment: @Mithoron Your suggested title was misleading, this atleast is in direct relation in what **I** want to know. And yes, Borax anion...that has been changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's important to understand that the simple integer hybridization labels *sp*, *sp<sup>2</sup>* and *sp<sup>3</sup>* are gross approximations and only accurately describe the electron density of simple symmetric molecules like $\ce{BeH2}$ and $\ce{CH4}$. Atoms in more complex molecules (even something relatively simple like $\ce{H2O}$) cannot be described accurately using these labels. Instead, the contribution of atomic orbitals to localized bond orbitals must be described by non-integer combinations.

That said, the calculations you did are remarkably consistent with an *sp<sup>2</sup>* hybridization of oxygen [2]. If I understand the notation correctly, it says that the bond from O[2] to B[1] is ~90% *p* (roughly a pure *p* orbital), while the other bond to B[3] is ~75% p (i.e. *sp<sup>3</sup>*). The two lone pairs on the oxygen average 67% *p*, perfectly *sp<sup>2</sup>*.

We are able to average the two lone pair orbitals because electrons are completely interchangeable and are not localized to a specific lone pair. Any hybrid orbital description that captures the combined electron density of the four electrons in the two non-bonding orbitals is acceptable.

So the oxygen can be described as having two *sp<sup>2</sup>* nonbonding orbitals, an *sp<sup>3</sup>* bonding orbital and a nearly pure *p* bonding orbital. That's pretty close to *sp<sup>2</sup>* hybridization, where we expect three *sp<sup>2</sup>* orbitals and one pure *p*. The only deviation here is the shift of ~ 10% *s* from one of the *sp<sup>2</sup>* orbitals to the *p* orbital, so that we end up with an *sp<sup>3</sup>* and a not-quite-pure *p* instead.

Comment: Your interpretation was correct, Thanks for the explanation, can please explain how did you average?...say for lone pair, I did (5.78/2) ....and what you did was adding the percentages and obtaining a ratio. Also, last paragraph implies that as long as we donot have nearly 100\% p character, we cannot say the bond is $sp^2$ am i correct?

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi - The reason you cannot do 5.78/2 is that the 4.7 and 1.1 p contributions aren't normalized. They are only relative to an s value of 1. To give them equal weight, you need to add 4.7/(4.7+1) + 1.1/(1.1+1), where the denominator represents the total s + p contribution. These normalized values are the percentages shown in parentheses in your calculation. For your second question, I guess you are talking about the B-O bond that is sp3? Yes, it's sp3, but the original statement is that the oxygen atom is approximately sp2 hybridized, which is roughly true.

Comment: This answer is extrapolating from incomplete data on a very, very crude level of theory. It's probably also using an NBO version years deprecated and the data which is actually not meant to be interpreted. It's not even clear that the structural data is sound. Sure, this is one way or interpreting it, but in my opinion, this is a more misleading interpretation than just guessing hybridisation from the structure with Coulson's theorem (given a crystal structure of something).

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Supposedly as the website states, Gaussian 16 is used, and Gaussian 16 uses relatively newer version of NBO as indicated in the answer. Structural data is sound? (structure of NBO or the compound)....and Apply coulson's theorem on the most optimised geometry of Borax( the B.angle is 109), you get sp3 as opposed all over the internet

Comment: @Martin-マーチン - fair point about the theory. I was approaching the question as being specifically about why the calculated result did not match OP's expectation and simply pointing out that it does match. Whether or not the expectation and the calculation correctly describe the situation is a different question.

Comment: @pipiedipie You do not cite any details for the calculation. While Gaussian is certainly able to interface to newer versions of NBO (i.e. 6 or 7), it only has implemented version 3.1, which is deprecated for more than a decade now. Even if the older version works for this molecule, there is still the issue of the crude level of theory and whether you are actually interpreting data from a true (or even the global) minimum. On another note, I don't see much benefit in describing binding within the constraints of hybridisation for this molecule.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン yes right, should have cited. Also, if you meant least energy state by global minimum, it supposedly should be, because I tried tera-chem G.O. and OCRA G.O. before Gaussian (All on same theory).. And also as Andrew stated, i wanted to know how does this work, so might say a fault of the question